# Get more many valid location after upgrade Xcode6.2 to Xcode7.2

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am using the SignificantLocationChanges services to require the location. But after updated Xcode6.2 to Xcode7.2, we get more valid location(longitude/latitude is 0). My source code like this:

```
let authStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
if authStatus == CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted || authStatus == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied {
  return
}
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.delegate = self
if authStatus == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined {
  myLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
}
locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let lastLocation = locations.last
        if let last = lastLocation {
            latitudeLabel.text = "(location.coordinate.latitude)"
            longitudeLabel.text = "(location.coordinate.longitude)"
        }
    }
```

Because the source code is same and we only upgrade the xcode version, this seems like the xcode caused this issue.This issue doesn't occur in all devices, about only occurred in 20% of our all user devices.
Somebody has same issue or any clue to look for the cause, please tell me

Comment: What do you mean by Get more many valid location ?

Comment: we can get CLLocation object, but this coordinate.latitude/longitude both is 0.

Comment: Have to placed location key in info.plist ?

Comment: Yes, we put the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription into plist. I don't know why location changed. we only upgraded the Xcode version. Thanks for your confirmation.

Comment: Are you running app on simulator ? Or device ?

Comment: We run the app on device, not simulator.

Comment: will you print lastLocation at console? and lat and long ?

Comment: This issue only occurred 20% of our users(we have one hundred thousand users almostly), we can look these logs of application running, and can not reproduced this issue.. Actually in our testing, latitude/longitude items never have 0 data. I am sorry I didn't explain this point. we wonder that what caused the issue after only upgraded the Xcode.

Comment: it is really hard to bottle neck the issue then unless you able to replicate.Try with different scenario like slow internet, inside buildings disabling location. No internet.

Comment: I will try doing it, thank you. Is it possible if xcode was upgraded, the api of iOS framework would be changed? we don't change the [Deployment Target]. we may miss some point when we upgraded the xcode.

Comment: you might want to check didFailedToUpload Locaton for error.

Comment: It makes sense, func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error), func locationManager(CLLocationManager, didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError: Error), I will try to acquire these feedback from these method. Thank you!

Comment: let us know what happens, good luck